# Decrypt an object in AWS S3 without downloading it to local system

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I have an encrypted file at an s3 bucket. I want to decrypt it programmatically without downloading it to my local machine. Is it possible to decrypt an encrypted file without downloading it to my local machine?

Things I'm using to encrypt the file:
boto3 library, KMS keys for encryption
aws sdk , python script

I can definitely download this file and then decrypt it in my local machine like this:

```
with aws_encryption_sdk.stream(
    mode='d',
    source=src_file,
    key_provider=kms_key
    ) as decryptor:
        for block in decryptor:
            tgt_file.write(block)
```

But this is possible if I download the file to the local system. I don't want to download the file. I want to decrypt it inside the s3 bucket and enable the next process to work on this decrypted file.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible directly.  However, you could create an AWS Lambda so that when the file uploads you could run a Lambda to do the decryption.  See [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) for more details.

In pseudo code you'd do something like:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context): 
    read file from key in the event from S3
    decrypt file as your code shows
    save decrypted file back to S3 likely in a different bucket or directory path
    notify next process that the decrypted file is available.
```

Comment: With this solution, I would suggest to save the decrypted file to another S3 location (and have only the next process have access), otherwise why encrypt it in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your response @stdunbar but looks like one can't use aws_ecryption_sdk using lambda function.  I am getting an error as below:                                            
`Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'aws_encryption_sdk'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}`

Comment: @NavneetThakur - can you post more code like your `setup.py`?  I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @stdunbar : Here is the code that I'm running:  (Part - 1)                                             
`import json
import boto3
import aws_encryption_sdk
import boto3
import os
from shutil import make_archive
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    kms_key = aws_encryption_sdk.KMSMasterKeyProvider(key_ids=['arn:aws:kms:us-west-1:XXX:key/XXXXXXXXX'])
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`

Comment: Part 2:                                                                                                                
`#Below code copies the cipher_specimen1.txt file to s3 bucket navneettempe and renames it cipher_wages.txt
    
    copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'navneettempe',
    'Key': 'cipher_specimen1.txt'
    }
    s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'navneettempe','cipher_wages.txt')
    
    ct_file='cipher_wages.txt'
    pt_file='wages.txt'
     `

Comment: Part 3:  `#Below code decrypts the cipher_wages.txt using the same KMS key that was used to encrypt the file
    with aws_encryption_sdk.stream(
  mode='d',
  source=ct_file,
  key_provider=kms_key
  ) as decryptor:
      for block in decryptor:
          pt_file.write(block)`